# PendingIntent with PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to understand the behavior of `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`. I want to know when it will return `null` and when it won't.
This is the order of events happening:

```
alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class)
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Now, when I run:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
```

it returns a non-null value.
Now my question is is it returning a non-null value because I had created a pendingIntent with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or is it because I had called `manager.setInexactRepeated(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` will return null only if the system dont find the intent.

If system don't find it, it will not create one since you flag as "dont create" and system will return null.

If you already created a intent first and pass it to alarm manager, system will return a non-null value until that alarm expires or until you cancel that alarm.